Получите массив позиций всех цифр 3 кроме первой и последней
Я получил массив позиций всех цифр 3, но надо всех, кроме первой и последней.


const num = 303030333
let regexp = /([3])/g;
let res;
let aaa = [];
while ((res = regexp.exec(num))) {
  aaa.push(res.index);
}
console.log(aaa);






const num = 130303033302;
console.log(Array.from(num.toString().matchAll(/3/g), x => x.index).slice(1, -1))




Cпасибо, но это не совсем подходит, ибо если перед первой или последней тройкой поставить любую цифру, то в массив запишутся все индексы вхождений). Т.е если num = 130303033302, то он отправит массив все индексы, а нужны все акромя первого и последнего

Огромное спасибо. Я уже сделал также, но вот знаний в regex нехватает. Пошёл изучать. Ещё раз огромное спасибо
